# Why is there a need to add outline to CSS? Is outline redundant to the existing ones?

Tags: css

Today I notice outline propery in CSS. However I don't know why it is added to CSS? What for?
For me, margin, padding, border is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outline` creates a border outside the element's area, *not adding to its width and not influencing the surrounding layout*. From the [quirksmode.org page on `outline`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/outline.html):

> The outline is not actually a part of the box, it does not count in any way towards the width or height of a box.

That is a very useful feature indeed, because it allows e.g. highlighting an element on `hover` / `focus` actions without disturbing the neighboring elements. The slight dotted outline around focused links in Firefox is done using the `outline` property.

It's not supported by IE < 8, though, so it's only of limited everyday use.

- [Quirksmode.org compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Answer (score 2):

A quick google, http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=outline+css, leads to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/) which mentions that you can kill the dotted borders on anchors and such with outline.

To add, it's a border that doesn't take up space of the element and doesn't shift things around. Can be useful for debugging. Also not supported in IE6/IE7.

Answer (score 2):

[For this reason :)](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)

Notice the dotted border around the image:

[image]

It is used to remove that.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I didn't make the connection between the ugly dotted outline and the CSS property until now! This is very useful.

Comment: More importantly, it is used to **add** the border in the first place. Knowing where the focus is is a *very* **very** useful thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually used to indicate focus from what I understand. If you look at some people's CSS resets, they will do something like this:

```
*:focus { outline: none; }
```

You'll see it mostly around anchor tags if you just open up a page and starting pressing TAB a bunch of times you should see different links have the outline applied unless the stylesheet specifically says not to.